# PHP: How to extract from a (multibyte) string all predefined substrings?

Tags: php, string, multibyte

I'd like to split a string (representing a word) into letters and predefined multi-letter sequences. In other words I'd like to extract predefined substrings  form a string matching in a "greedy" way and in order in which they occur.

For example if I my array of substrings contained all latin letters plus Polish digraphs: `['ch', 'cz', 'dz', 'dź', 'dż', 'rz', 'sz']` then `szczebrzeszyn` would be parsed into `['sz', 'cz', 'e', 'b', 'rz', 'e', 'sz', 'y', 'n']`.

Of course I could write some nested loops comparing character by character, but maybe there is some creative and more efficient way to obtain such result using the built-in string functions? How can I do this in PHP in an efficient and multi-byte safe way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/sz|cz|\X/u', 'wszczęcie', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => w
            [1] => sz
            [2] => cz
            [3] => ę
            [4] => c
            [5] => i
            [6] => e
        )
)
```

So the above code seems to do the job. The important points are: the substrings are matched in the order they are provided, so longer ones should go first (`'cz'` should be matched before `'c'`, etc.). And the `u` flag is important to make it multi-byte safe.

Comment: There seem to be a mismatch between your input and output example: https://www.ideone.com/yVZOEW

Comment: Also it seems https://www.ideone.com/Q2Q3Vo produces something different from expected output.

Comment: @Havenard ad 1. You're right. I wanted to show it's multibyte-safe, changed the example and forgot to update the input. Correcting now. Thanks. ad 2. For the sake of brevity, I reduced the the number of digraphs to the ones relevant for this particular example.